# How to stop Firefox's version 64.0 from showing the update nag screen?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, privacy, automatic-update

> **Edit 24. May 2019: The accepted answer doesn't work for version 66.0.5 (64 Bit), at least not for me. (And I assume it doesn't work for any other new version.)**

I have Firefox 64.0 (64-bit) running on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I'm totally sick of the update nag screen showing up seemingly once daily or even more often.

Even more I'm sick of the FACT that Firefox connects somewhere to the Mozilla website to check for new versions: The Update nag screen info changed to suggesting to update to 65.0 from suggesting to 64.1 before.

What I have done so far: I have read MANY webpages about this topic, and I have changed nearly all http:// and https:// addresses in about:config

**My Question: Is there a way to stop the update nag screen?**
(*Bonus question:* Is there a way by modifying Firefox through the UI, through about:config, with notepad++ or with the help of for example winrar to modify the .jar files from stopping Firefox to connect to Mozilla's update servers to check for the newest version.)

(If NOT, then Bye-bye Firefox.)

And btw, I'm surfing on a small mobile MB-contingent of fast data transfer, so hitting the update button once accidentally could simply either stop me from using the internet probably for up to a month, or COST REAL LIFE MONEY for more MB quota.

**09.May.2019 Look out!!** I manually downloaded the Firefox 65.0.5 installation file, and then let it run: **It didn't carry over the distribution directory and the policies.json file in it!!! What do they think?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Is there a way to stop the update nag screen?

Yes. Read on.

> The option to Never check for updates was removed from `about:preferences`. You can use the [DisableAppUpdate](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md) enterprise policy as a substitute.

Source [Firefox 63.0, See All New Features, Updates and Fixes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/63.0/releasenotes/)

> Policies can be specified using the Group Policy templates on Windows
>   (https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/tree/master/windows),
>   configuration profiles on macOS
>   (https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/tree/master/mac), or by
>   creating a file called `policies.json`.
>
> On Windows, create a directory called distribution where the EXE is
>   located and place the file there.
>
> On Mac, the file goes into
>   Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution.
>
> On Linux, the file goes into firefox/distribution, where firefox is
>   the installation directory for firefox, which varies by distribution.

...

> **DisableAppUpdate**
>
> This policy turns off application updates.
>
> ```
> {
>   "policies": {
>     "DisableAppUpdate": true
>   }
> }
> ```

Source [policy-templates/README.md at master · mozilla/policy-templates](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md)

So create a file called `policies.json` containing:

```
{
    "policies": {
    "DisableAppUpdate": true
    }
}
```

And place it in the appropriate directory as documented above.

Answer (score -2):

First, you type about:preferences#advanced in the address bar.
Under Advanced,  Select Update.

[v56+] Type about:preferences#general in the address bar.
Select Update.then select the option of name i.e never check updates and also turn off Use a background service to install updates

Comment: That was removed in v63.0. See my answer.