# How to stop Firefox's newest (65.0.5) version from checking for updates when opening the Help->About Firefox window?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, privacy, firefox-automatic-updates

I have Firefox 65.0.5 (64-bit) running on Windows 7 Home Premium. (I use Firefox with German language setting.)

After the certificate disaster of Firefox, I was forced to update to 65.0.5.

Sadly, when in the menu selecting Help->About Firefox the pop-up window shows a small loading circle beside the text "search for updates", and after like 2 or 3 seconds it replaces the circle and the text with the text "Firefox is up to date".

**Is it possible and if yes how to stop Firefox's newest (65.0.5) version from checking for updates when opening the Help->About Firefox window?**

I strongly tend to *believe* - I might be wrong - that this checking for updates within the viewing that pop up window was not active in my 64.0 version, and I *believe* it was turned off by the policies.json trick on my 64.0 version. (Lately, I managed to stop Firefox 64.0 from showing the update nag screen with the help from superuser DavidPostill.

- [How to stop Firefox's new versions from showing the update nag screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1407844/how-to-stop-firefoxs-new-versions-from-showing-the-update-nag-screen)

First thing I checked after the update was if the policies.json directive was kept by the update. But how to check? I went to the firefox.exe directory, and the distribution-folder was gone! 
Fine, I recreated the folder and the policies.json file in it and restarted the browser, but sadly that didn't help with the question here.

Comment: You need to confirm the behavior changed for us.  You should downgrade to Firefox 64, implement the same fix to prevent it from being upgraded, and see if it behaves the way you think it does.  You should be able to use the Firefox Profile manager to accomplish this.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I don't have to. The reference to the 64 version is just for more information. But the main question stays the same: Could I turn of the checking for the updates when opening the window at Help->About Firefox. But I restructed the question.

Comment: 1. Try stop firefox from notifying me about updates https://superuser.com/questions/1325421 2. Try creating policies.json https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson 3. Possibliy move to firefox developer with more access to settings http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3041858 https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/