# How to stop Firefox's version 66.0.5 (64-Bit) from showing the update nag screen?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security, privacy, automatic-update

I asked the [same question for version 64.0](https://superuser.com/questions/1407844/how-to-stop-firefoxs-version-64-0-from-showing-the-update-nag-screen), and [the then accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1407933/540538) worked. For the 66.0.5 (64-Bit) version on Windows 7 Home Premium it doesn't work anymore.

I had to install the 66.0.5 version, I did it by downloading the installation file (xx MegaByte) and starting it locally. It deleted the distribution-folder. I recreated it and the policies file.

But today I got the update nag screen again, asking me to update to Firefox 67.

> **How to stop in version 66.0.5 (64-Bit) on Windows 7 Home Premium the update nag screen?**

**(And how to stop Firefox to contact the Mozilla servers for checking for new versions?!!!)**

Would

```
{
  "policies": {
    "DisableAppUpdate": true,
    "AppUpdateURL": "https://0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

in the policies.json file help?

Comment: FF67 adds many security feature. You should use it. If you don't want to update try Firefox ESR.